# How to read csv file in which one colum has space separated numbers

Tags: r, csv

How can I read a two-column csv file in which columns are delimited by commas but the second column has a bunch of numbers split by spaces? Another issue is that the number of values in the second column varies a lot so I don't how to accommodate for this in R. I did this in MATLAB using a cell array but I've no idea what to do next in R. If it helps, I'm only interested on the second column and I'd like to do operations on it( ex : sum of column,standard deviation,etc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to read the dataset using `read.csv` and then `split` the space separated `col2` using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(dat, 'Col2', sep=' ')
 #   Col1 Col2_1 Col2_2 Col2_3 Col2_4 Col2_5 Col2_6
 #1:   25     35    -24    325      2      7      9
 #2:   28     24      8      9     10     11     NA
```

Or you can change the `,` to `' '` and then use `read.table` to read the dataset with `fill=TRUE`

```
 read.table(text=gsub(',', ' ', readLines('spaceSep.csv')),
                                    sep='', skip=1, fill=TRUE)

 # V1 V2  V3  V4 V5 V6 V7
 #1 25 35 -24 325  2  7  9
 #2 28 24   8   9 10 11 NA
```

If you don't need the first column,

```
dat1 <- read.table(text=gsub(".*,", "", readLines('spaceSep.csv')),
                                                 skip=1, fill=TRUE)
```

and you can get the `sum`, `sd` etc for each column

```
colSums(dat1, na.rm=TRUE)
#V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 
#59 -16 334  12  18   9 

apply(dat1,2, sd, na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
dat <- read.csv('spaceSep.csv')
dat <- structure(list(Col1 = c(25L, 28L), Col2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), 
.Label = c(" 24 8 9 10 11", " 35 -24 325 2 7 9"), class = "factor")),
.Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! All the different solutions are amazing too! I'd upvote you but I don't have enough points, I'll do it as soon as I get them.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the space to comma(such as, in Linux: sed s/ /,/g 1.txt or just use the notepad and substitute all space)! and than read it via read.csv.